# Responsive div buttons inside Image

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, masonry

I have a gallery of masonry images and I want to place on each image a div with buttons.

My problem is that the div is not responsive and when I reduce the screen some buttons disappear rather than slow down and follow the movement of the screen.

I intend that by decreasing the screen the buttons will decrease and still appear all within the div.

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="mdc-image-list mdc-image-list--masonry masonry-image-list second">
      <li class="mdc-image-list__item" *ngFor="let image of list; let  i = index;">
          <img [src]="image" class="mdc-image-list__image">
        <div class="mdc-image-list--with-text-protection">
          <div class="mdc-image-list__supporting">
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem to solve here is to align the icons next to each other, *without* using `margin-left` or `float: left;`. You can do this with `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` to the parent class (`.mdc-image-list__label`). This makes sure that each item gets displayed next to each other **and** the `space-between` ensures that there is equal space between each element. Read more about flexbox at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng9ixj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss) for the adjustments.

```css
.Pin{
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Inbox{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Chat{
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Task{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

// Adjusting this class
.mdc-image-list__label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box; // To make sure it encapsulates the padding styling
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Individual class to each image is unwarranted, so you can remove it and it's related css as well. The below css will fix your issue, it's more generic and better.

```
.mdc-image-list__supporting a {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.mdc-image-list__supporting a img {
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   cursor: pointer;
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```